# choose the best fit between small dataset and large dataset

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, data-analysis

I am currently working on a small project .

So what my problem is like I have multiple delivery partners and have two parameters regarding that, first is total order assigned per delivery partner and their success rate.

Like

```
Partner | Total Order Assigned | Success Rate(IN percent)
A       | 100                  | 70
B       | 10                   | 50
C       | 50                   | 40
D       | 4                    | 90
```

So, if a new order arrives, I want to assign that order to one of the delivery partner on the basis of success rate and total order assigned so far. So in the above example D has the most success rate but has only assigned 4 orders but A has the more order assigned though and has decent success rate.

So how can i approach this problem.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: @desertnaut why not migrate this question to cross validated or data science? or point the user to ask there?

Comment: @user2160809 because IMHO the question is too broad for there as well; CV and DS (like SO) are not "anything-goes"...

Comment: ok i think i know now what you mean. you don't mean just broad but also that it's not that well formulated. i can see your point..

Answer (score -1):

This is a imbalanced classification problem. There are a number of ways to deal with this like over/under-sampling https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317601/how-to-deal-with-a-highly-unbalanced-classification-problem

I'm not sure though you can do machine learning with a class of 4 samples though, so you might actually end up ignoring this delivery partner all together. You can have a look at scikit-learn cheat sheet when choosing a model
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html

Comment: @aayush I can't comment on the question yet but can someone move the question to cross validated instead of down voting my answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @user2160809. But can you explain me in quite breif as how can I apply oversampling in this situation.

Comment: @aayush such questions are better asked in cross validated https://stats.stackexchange.com but anyways i wouldn't do oversampling with 4 samples i think

Comment: Ok!! Thanks @user2160809  btw, I have now asked it there.